# Type error: Cannot read property offsetTop of null react. Unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm having a problem with a react component I made, which animates its children into view once the user has scrolled past a certain point on the page. The animation functionality works fine, but upon unmounting it's throwing an error.

I'm using this component on a page which will unmount this component based on the screen size.

However, once this component has been unmounted because the screen has been resized I'm getting a type error where it is still trying to read the offsetTop property of the reference used to locate the height of the element on the screen, which no longer exists.

```
export const AppearHOC = ({children, isMobile}) => {

      const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(false)
      const myRef = useRef()
      
      useEffect(() => {

                  const checkHeight = (ref) => {
                        
                        const elementHeight = ref.current.offsetTop - 500
                        
                        if (window.pageYOffset > elementHeight && isVisible === false) {
                              setVisible(true)
                        } else if (window.pageYOffset < elementHeight && isVisible === true) {
                              setVisible(false)
                        }
                  }
                  // Check scroll height and change visible state if necessary
                  
                  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => checkHeight(myRef), {passive: true})
                  return () => {
                        window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => checkHeight(myRef), {passive: true});
                  }
            
      }, [myRef, isVisible, isMobile])

      return(
            <ComponentContainer ref={myRef}>
                  <CSSTransition
                        in={isVisible ? true : false}
                        classNames={'appear'}
                        timeout={1000}
                        unmountOnExit
                        ref={myRef}
                  >
                        <ComponentSlider>
                              {children}
                        </ComponentSlider>
                  </CSSTransition>
                  <CSSTransition
                        in={isVisible ? false : true}
                        classNames={'appear'}
                        timeout={1000}
                        unmountOnExit
                        
                  >
                        <ComponentScrollHint icon={faChevronDown}/>
                  </CSSTransition>
            </ComponentContainer>
      )
}
```

I've tried using the "isMobile" property to make the function return before reading the offsetTop property when necessary - but this did not work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => checkHeight(myRef), {passive: true})`, you're actually removing a handler that was never registered. The one you actually registered is not removed since you used an anonymous arrow function and have no reference to it.
You could do:

```
const handler = () => checkHeight(myRef);
// ... register
window.addEventListener('scroll', handler, {passive: true});
// ... later
window.removeEventListener('scroll', handler);
```